# String returns null after leaving child, when retrieving from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I'm fetching data from firebase realtime database, into my flutter application using the following code.

```
class homeScreen extends StatelessWidget{
   final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
   final String dataToFetch;
   String name;

...
   getData(name, dataToFetch);
...
   void getData(String name, String dataToFetch){
      DBRef.child("dataToFetch").once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot){
         name = dataSnapShot.value;
         print("one $name");
   });
   print("two $name");
  }
}
```

I have tried using:

```
return name;
```

In both getData and in DBRef.child.

The problem I have is that DBRef.child finds exactly what I am looking for and prints that out in the console "one ". But the string becomes null when leaving the child, so the last print says "two NULL".

My question is, how can I keep what I am retriving in DBRef.child and return that value to my other code?

**UPDATE**

Here is the updated code, thanks to @danypata.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class homeScreenFam extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<homeScreenFam>{
  final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  String name;

  @override
  void initState(){
    print("1: $name");
    super.initState();
    getData(name, "keyThatIWant");
    print("1.5: $name");
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    print("2: $name");
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffe9e9e9),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Welcome $name!",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void getData(String name, String dataToFetch) async{
    DBRef.child(dataToFetch).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot){
      setState(() { // this will trigger the build method
        name = dataSnapShot.value;  // we update the new value.
        print("3: $name");
      });
      print("4: $name");
    });
    print("5: $name");
  }
}
```

The problem persists, just look at the output of the console.

```
Restarted application in 1 309ms.
I/flutter (26334): 1: null
I/flutter (26334): 5: null
I/flutter (26334): 1.5: null
I/flutter (26334): 2: null
I/flutter (26334): 3: <RightName>
I/flutter (26334): 4: <RightName>
I/flutter (26334): 2: null
```

As we see, 1 should obviously be null, because we have no name yet. So we want  on the following places, 2,3,4,5. But only 3 and 4 are .

If I write "await" before DBRef.child... then I get the following output

```
Restarted application in 1 269ms.
I/flutter (26334): 1: null
I/flutter (26334): 1.5: null
I/flutter (26334): 2: null
I/flutter (26334): 3: <RightName>
I/flutter (26334): 4: <RightName>
I/flutter (26334): 5: <RightName>
I/flutter (26334): 2: null
```

Now we're only missing 1.5 and 2. I'm guessing that it has something to do with void. But I am not sure, what small thing am I missing?

**UPDATE 2**

```
  void getData(String paramName, String dataToFetch) async{
    DBRef.child(dataToFetch).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot){
      setState(() { // this will trigger the build method
        paramName = dataSnapShot.value;  // we update the new value.
        print("3: $paramName");
      });
      print("4: $paramName");
    });
    print("5: $paramName");
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.5 & 5 should be null all the time. There is a name conflict on the ```getData``` method, please change the param ```name``` to ```paramName``` and try again.

Comment: @danypata Still not getting it to work. I updated the code so you can se if I did it right.

Comment: you did it wrong, please check my edited answer. It shouldn't be ```paramName =```, it should be ```name=```.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of async execution of the code, to fix it you'll have to wait for the execution. Like this:

```
void getData(String name, String dataToFetch) async{ // NOTE THE ASYNC HERE
    //use await to wait for async execution
    String value = await DBRef.child("dataToFetch").once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot){
         name = dataSnapShot.value;
         print("one $name");
         return name;
   });
   print("two $value");
  }
```

**UPDATE**
If you call this method from the state of a `StatefullWidget` this is how you should implement it:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String name; // this property will be updated by the getData

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData(name, "theKeyYouWant"); // call getData in init state
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test App'),
      ),
      body: Text(name)
    );
  }


  void getData(String paramName, String dataToFetch) async {
    DBRef.child("dataToFetch").once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot){
      setState(() { // this will trigger the build method
        name = dataSnapShot.value;  // we update the new value.
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the error: "The value of the local variable 'value' isn't used.

And I copied the code exactly, thank you for helping me though.

Comment: @Caption it was missing the opening ```{``` for the method, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I saw that, but that's not the problem.

It doesn't even print out one and two...

Comment: right after String value = await...

It freezes, or something. Because if I place a print before that, it prints out fine, but if I place a print after String value, nothing prints, not even null.

I appreciate all the help you're giving me!

Comment: do you think you know the solution? I still can't get it to work :/

Comment: It is really wired, I've tested on a test project and for me it was working. Is the key ```dataToFetch``` correct ? The only way that code should "freeze" is if the snapshot is not returned or an error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be working now, I changed nothing and it just worked haha... 

Is there a way to set a wait or delay after the call of getData?, because it fetches the data after it goes in to the MaterialApp. So the name comes ut as NULL. But in the function, it prints out the name perfectly.

I am very thankful for the help you're giving me!

Comment: @Caption I've updated my answer, please check it out ;).

Comment: alrighty, so I tired your code but I am still having problems. See the orginalpost for updated code with inputs. Thanks again! :)